# Reinstall of Microsoft Office 2010 beta isn't prompting me for upgrade vs. side-by-side installation options

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2007, office-2010-beta

I'm running Office 2007 on Windows 7.  When I ran the Microsoft Office 2010 beta installation,  it asked if I wanted to upgrade the existing 2007 installation or install along side 2007.  I later uninstalled 2010 and rebooted.  When I re-ran the Office 2010 setup program, it no longer asked if I wanted to upgrade or install side by side.  It just did a side by side install by default.  How can I get it to re-prompt me, as I'd now like to upgrade my 2007 install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably there were some elements of 2010 left behind when you uninstalled which knew that you were, in a way, upgrading 2010. Try to uninstall again using [Revouninstaller](http://www.revouninstaller.com/). This will (more) ensure that everything is gone. Then reinstall.